# Send SharePoint list information through an Email

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I send details of SharePoint List Items though email **without** SharePoint development.

i.e

I have a list with 5 columns, and I want to send an automated email once the list item is saved ,which should include details of all 5 columns.

I know Workflow wouldn't help

I am using SharePoint 2010

Comment: If you want to this WITHOUT development, then why are you here on StackOverflow? Maybe you want to visit http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think alert will help you in this case, set an alert at list level so that when an item is added it will notify the user with email address.

But this thing to work , you must have Outbound email setup in central administration.

Hope this helps